# Sql equivalent of this dax

Tags: mysql, sql, powerbi, dax

I have a table in power bi which uses the below dax:

need inputs on SQL Query.

powerbi table name: demo,

employee is another table and demo table uses it and **KEY** IS ALREADY CREATED IN EMPLOYEE TABLE BY CONCATINATING employee'[EMP_CODE]&'employee'[dob]

```
key=SUMMARIZE( FILTER('employee','employee'[emp_STS]="working"),'employee'[EMP_CODE],'employee'[dob],"Key",'employee'[EMP_CODE]&'employee'[dob])

WORKEDHOURS = CALCULATE(MAX('Employee'[workhrs]), 'Empployee'[NAME]<>BLANK())

employeecode=SUMMARIZE( FILTER('employee','employee'[emp_STS]="working"),'employee'[EMP_CODE],'employee'[dob],"Key",'employee'[EMP_CODE]&'employee'[dob])

employeedob=SUMMARIZE( FILTER('employee','employee'[emp_STS]="working"),'employee'[EMP_CODE],'employee'[dob],"Key",'employee'[EMP_CODE]&'employee'[dob])
```

corresponding SQL Query I have tried :

```
select KEY,
CASE
WHEN NAME IS NOT NULL THEN MAX(HOURS) 
END AS WORKEDHOURS,
EMP_CODE,
EMP_DOB
from employee where EMP_STS='WORKING' GROUP BY KEY,QC_NAME,DOB,EMP_CODE
```

Comment: you have 2 expressions. they are seems to be independent. Can you make DAX expression that you want to get in SQL more clear?

Comment: Hi @Mik, I have updated the question. so basically there are 4 columns in the demo table (key,workedhours,employeecode,employeedob) which uses these formulas. I want to write SQL query for those columns in a table.

Comment: Hi, It's hard to give a good answer without debugging. What I would try, I would create 4 tables and the left join it.

Comment: Hi, as per the requirement I need to have all columns in one table

Comment: That's why I wrote - left join it., as a result this returns 1 table.

Comment: employeecode ,employeedob,key are clones, guess it should be a different code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check this part and come with your feedback.

```
WITH
e1 AS (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT([EMP_CODE],[dob]) AS [Key]
        ,EMP_CODE
        ,EMP_DOB
    FROM employee 
    WHERE [emp_STS]='working'
    GROUP BY [EMP_CODE],[dob]
    )
,e2 AS(
    SELECT 
        CONCAT([EMP_CODE],[dob]) AS [Key]
        ,MAX([workhrs]) AS [WorkedHours]
        FROM employee 
    WHERE [NAME] IS NOT NULL -- ,[emp_STS]='working' ?
    GROUP BY [EMP_CODE] ,[dob]
    )

SELECT     
    e1.[Key]
    ,e1.[EMP_CODE]
    ,e1.[EMP_DOB]
    ,e2.[WorkedHours]
FROM e1
LEFT JOIN e2
ON e1.[Key]=e2.[Key]
```

Comment: Hi @Mik, but got a doubt what about the Empployee'[NAME]<>BLANK() that is provided in WORKEDHOURS

Comment: Hej @SandeepMohanty, please check the new one

Comment: Hi @Mik, the output table requires all columns  i.e Key, workedhours, employeecode, employeedob

Comment: I understand it, but it's easer to debug  a short request

Comment: ok, looking trough you sql, I wrote the final version. Please, check.

Comment: Hi @Mik, do I need need to add the  emp_sts in e2 also?

Comment: Please, change to e1 for EMP_DOB. I also changed it in the answer.

Comment: Do I need to add the condition emp_sts='Working' in e2 also?? you have given question mark on that.

Comment: It should not affect the result. Join can work faster if you add, but I’m not sure.

Comment: You can try both. But the result should be the same.

Comment: Ok I am trying it out , will let you know

Comment: Glad to hear, you're welcome )